# Disney movie with a teenage android?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching a movie on TV when I was a kid, so in the mid- to late-80's. I expect it was a Disney movie, as at that age the majority of movies I watched were on the "Sunday Night Disney Movie" special (on ABC, I think).

The movie featured a "teenage" kid who was a robot/android, built by his "father."  The kid looked fully human. I seem to recall that when his batteries were running low, he spoke, and likely moved slowly.

The only scene I recall involved him asking a stranger (perhaps after ringing their front door bell?) if he could use their outlet, and they were confused, and showed him to the bathroom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like *[Not Quite Human](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093649/)* which was a Disney TV production from the late 80's.

[image]

Comment: LOL rip-off of Small Wonder

Comment: Once again i'm late at answering one that i knew right off the bat...

Comment: @Shane At first glance, one could think that, but the Disney made-for-tv-movies were actually based on a series of books by Seth McEvoy which date back to 1986 http://www.amazon.com/Reckless-Robot-Not-Quite-Human/dp/0671600842/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1328856055&sr=1-4

Comment: @Shawn Touche. So Small Wonder probably ripped off the books. Live and learn.